# name 'Spinbox' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

These are my imports.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
```

The code:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('TITLE')

spin = Spinbox(window, from_ = 0, to = 99, width = 5, bd = 8)
spin.grid(column = 0, row = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

If I use ttk, Spinbox will be defined, but bd doesn't work either which doesn't make sense for me.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import messagebox as msg

window = tk.Tk()

spin = ttk.Spinbox(window, from_ = 0, to = 99, width = 5, bd = 8)
spin.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

This is the way I tried to solve it. But, "bd" wasn't defined.

Comment: _"If I use ttk"_ How do you use `ttk`?

Comment: @Thomas Sablik I tried using ttk on Spinbox, but unfortunately, didn't work at all since bd did not work.

Comment: Please show how you tried it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik There you go. I hope this helps.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#spinbox doesn't have a parameter `bd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the

```
import tkinter as tk
```

import style, you need to use `tk` in front of all imported names:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('TITLE')

spin = tk.Spinbox(window, from_ = 0, to = 99, width = 5, bd = 8)
spin.grid(column = 0, row = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not ttk? Thank you.

Comment: You can use ttk.Spinbox, but all ttk widgets use the ttk.Style() to set the appearance, not arguments like tk widgets do. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-styling